# Using minipage inside tabu on new environment

Tags: minipage, tabu

I'm trying to create a new environment that creates a border for a minipage. This new environment is inside a class file. I'm using the code:

```
\newenvironment{quadro}{
\ignorespaces
\begin{tabu}{|c|}\hline
\begin{minipage}{.95\textwidth}
}{
\end{minipage}
\end{tabu}
}
```

It works perfectly if I use these commands outside the newenvironment structure, but when I use it this way, it returns the error "Missing $ inserted". Even if I move the final two commands to the upper part of the environment, it works, but then the environment would be of no use at all.

I would appreciate some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see, if the following works for you:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabu}

\newenvironment{quadro}{
\noindent
\begin{tabu}to\linewidth{|X|}
    \hline
}{
\end{tabu}\smallskip
}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}
\begin{quadro}
\lipsum*[11]
\end{quadro}
\lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

cells in `X` column type are `\parbox`es. therefore you not need `minipage`s.

[image]

Comment: That is it, worked perfectly. I didn't know the X columns are parboxes. Thank you.